# strip name from email in mysql without php is it possible?

Tags: mysql

HI all ,

i have a table with column `email` [someone@email.com] , i have 2.8 million records and i created a new column `user` and wish to add everything before the @ sign in the email field to the `user` field , is it possible with pure MySQL ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
UPDATE table
   SET user = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1)
```

Comment: Because links to the manual are always welcome: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: I does not remember whole url to write it down but I remember anything other for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the email column consists of "standard" well formed email addresses (i.e.: not X.400, etc.), you could populate the new `user` field based on the existing `email` field as follows:

```
UPDATE <table name> SET user = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1);
```

See the MySQL [String Functions manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.htm) for more information.

Comment: +1 Clinched it above the near-identical other answers with your link to docs. :)

Answer (score 1):

use a select like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('someone@email.com', '@', 1);
```

It returns someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SUBSTRING_INDEX function. Maybe something like this will do:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1)
```