# How to get the username from gmail and insert in the same table as different column in mysql

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a table named users. I have their email id in email column as "kayal@gmail.com", "suresh@yahoo.com", etc. I need a sql query to save the username(splitted from the email column like kayal, suresh, etc) column in the same existing table. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strip name from email in mysql without php is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235198/strip-name-from-email-in-mysql-without-php-is-it-possible)

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update users set username="SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, "@", 1)";
This made the trick.